# Unit Testing - dependent tests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I am creating a list of unit tests that are dependent on each other. For example, my first test creates a record in the database and checks that the return value is greater than 0.

The second test then checks the data of the record created in the first test. However, it needs the ID of the record produced in the first test.

Originally I called the second test from within the first test so that I could pass the ID as a parameter, which worked fine except this meant that essentially there was only one test.

I created an ordered list with the ID declared outside the scope but after the first unit test this value returns to 0 so obviously the second unit test fails.

Is there any way to create the tests so that they share the value produced in the first test?

The code is below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestNewLandlord_InsertIntoImportFiles_ReturnFileID()
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = EngineBllUtility.InsertIntoImportFiles(connString, @"C:\Documents and Settings\dTrunley\My Documents", "HFISNewLandlordTest.csv",
        "TestNewLandlord()", WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, "HFIS Landlords", "NA", 30247531, false);

        importFileId = long.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImportFileID"].ToString());
        Assert.IsTrue(importFileId > 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestNewLandlord_InsertIntoImportFiles_CorrectData()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
                String.Format("SELECT * FROM [mydeposits].[import].[ImportFiles] WHERE [ImportFileID] = {0}", importFileId), connectionString))
            {
                connectionString.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        bool correctData = true;
                        dr.Read();
                        if (!dr["ImportFileStatusID"].ToString().Equals("1"))
                            correctData = false;
                        if (!dr["HeadOfficeMemberID"].ToString().Equals("247531"))
                            correctData = false;
                        Assert.IsTrue(correctData);
                        TestCleanup();
                    }
                    else
                        throw new Exception("Import does not exist in database");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        TestCleanup();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Each test should be self contained. You don't even know in which order the test runner executes your test, there is no order to them!

Comment: I know, but the only way to do that is by creating a record with a constant ID

Comment: @DanielHilgarth They are executed in order..

Comment: Wrong. Your second unit test could be executed before the first unit test executed and thus no record was created at all. A self contained unit test creates its own test data in the setup and cleans up in the tear down

Comment: That's not guaranteed. Some test runners even shuffle the tests on purpose to make sure the tests don't depend on each other.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes but I have an ordered test list, which executes them in order.

Comment: Sorry to say that but you are using unit tests the wrong way.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I know how to create unit tests properly, I just don't have the time. I will implement them correctly next sprint, but for now this will do.

Comment: @user1016253 Please don't use the [unit] tag - it's ambiguous. [unit-testing] is what you want for UT questions.

Comment: "I will implement them correctly next sprint" - because there's always more time in the next sprint. Please post a follow-up comment if you actually do it; prove me wrong.

Comment: @TrueWill The sprint ended today, I have put a user story in the next sprint to properly develop these tests properly and I imagine it'd be the first thing I get to work on next sprint.

Comment: @user1016253 I applaud that. The issue is that the customers may perceive it as having no business value and may throw it out during prioritization (assuming XP's Planning Game). Paraphrasing Bob Martin, professionals keep their code clean all the time, because it's the only way to maintain a sustainable pace.

Comment: I totally understand the comments and answers to this question. However, is there really no dependency possible in .NET? That's so easy in JUnit or TestNG for Java.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am creating a list of unit tests that are dependent on each other. For example, my first test creates a record in the database and checks that the return value is greater than 0.

In my opinion, such approach is incorrect. You may create evil code that's going to bite you back. Such code:

- breaks the unit test principles
- is hard to maintain
- is very rigid, cumbersome and error-prone

Unit tests must be **independent**, or else don't write them at all. The reason for that is as the complexity of your software grow - so does the complexity of tests. If you have one test depends on others maintenance of the tests become a burden. So the cost of software increases, but the quality of code - doesn't. If you do not have dependencies between tests - the complexity of software doesn't matter as you can test each individual piece of functionality separately.

Another advantage is that you can run tests in parallel. For large systems, it is important that the Continuous Integration (and Deployment) cycle is fast. By running tests in parallel you could significantly speed up yout release cycle.

*Suggested solution*

What you are trying to accomplish are possibly the integration tests. One way to write them would be to create a separate project for such tests. Each test will still be independent of each other, but probably each test would require some `SetUp` and `TearDown` in NUnit test terms. So the SetUp would prepare everything that is required for the integration tests to pass and TearDown would perform a clean up after each test.

Comment: Looking back now...wow I really didn't understand unit testing

Comment: Can you justify the statement "*Unit test must be independent"*? Seems like common knowledge, but I never really hear reasons for it...

Comment: @naught101 just added couple of paragraphs: basically, it reduces the complexity of tests. You want tests to be as simple as possible so that you don't waste your brain energy on understanding the tests. This is a big problem in large systems. As a bonus, you can run tests in parallel, so that you speed up the test time. In practice, I saw about x2 to x8 times improvements in speed of tests run. Makes sense if it's 5 mins vs 40 mins and you release after each commit.

Comment: Not sure this is entirely true. It is true, that two unit tests must test two pieces of code independently, but I'm not sure it means that the two tests themselves must be independent. I think it might be a common misconception.

Answer (score 3):

That's very naughty, however you can un comment (if created by the test wizard or add)

```
//You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:

//Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
[ClassInitialize()]
public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
}

//Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
[ClassCleanup()]
public static void MyClassCleanup()
{
}

//Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
}

//Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
[TestCleanup()]
public void MyTestCleanup()
{
}
```

No different as such to mocking up some common tests data, though just as dubious.